# Bus instances Lifecycle and Best practices

Tags: c#, .net, rebus

While evaulating queueing mechanisms in general and Rebus in particular, I came up with the following questions about Bus Instances Lifecycle:

1. When need access to the Bus instance (one-way client mode) from several WCF services hosted on a windows service, the only option for instancing is on Singleton mode?
2. There is a way to Pause a Bus (stop dispatching message to the message handlers?) and then start it again.Or the only option is to dispose it and create a new one.

   - A use Case for this is when you connect to systems that have throughput limitations, or transactions per hour limits.
3. Can sagas have multiple workers, if so and assuming that the events were send on the correct order (initiator first), there is way to warranty that the initiator going to be handled first, there for creating the saga, before the following events are handled with multiple workers?
4. If in the same host, several Bus instances are used, and inside a message handler we call send on another bus instance based on the same configuration. The correlation-id wont be transmitted, And things like reply wont work properly, right?

I prefer concrete answers on how Rebus could support or not this, with code references/examples.

Comment: Primarily opinion based question are not a good fit for the Stackoverflow format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1: It's really simple: The bus instance (i.e. the implementation of `IBus` that gets put into the container and is handed to you when you do the `Configure.With(...)` configuration spells) is supposed to be a singleton instance that you keep around for the entire duration of your application's lifetime.

You can easily create multiple instances though, but that would be useful only for hosting multiple Rebus endpoints in the same process.

IOW the bus is fully reentrant and can safely be shared among threads in your web application.

2: Not readily, no - at least not in a way that is supported by the public API. You *can* do this though: `((RebusBus)bus).SetNumberOfWorkers(0)` (i.e. cast the `IBus` instance to `RebusBus` and change the number of worker threads), which will block until the number of workers has been adjusted to the desired number.

This way, you can actually achieve what you're after. It's just not an official feature of Rebus (yet), but it might be in the future. I can guarantee, though, that the ability to adjust the number of workers at runtime will not go away.

3: Yes, sagas are guarded by an optimistic concurrency scheme no matter which persistence layer you choose. If you're unsure which type of message will arrive first at your saga, you should make your saga tolerant to this - i.e. just implement `IAmInitiatedBy<>` for each potentially initiating message type and make the saga handle that properly.

Being (fairly) tolerant to out-of-order messages is a good general robustness principle that will serve you well also when messages are redelivered after having stayed a while in an error queue.

4: Rebus will pick up the current message context even though you're using multiple bus instances because it uses an ["ambient context"](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ploeh/archive/2007/07/23/ambientcontext.aspx) (i.e. a `MessageContext` instance mounted on the worker thread) to pick up the fact that you're sending a message from within a handler, which in turn will cause the correlation ID of the handled message to be copied to any outgoing messages.

Thus `bus.Reply` will work, too.

But as I stated in (1) the bus instance is fully reentrant and there's no need to have multiple instances around, unless they're actually logically difference endpoints.

I hope this answers your questions :)